# catalogue app and app approval rules

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I have been tasked to produce an app that is essentially a quarterly publication with industry related news.  Its approx. ten pages of PDF's that I have to turn into something fancy.  I always thought Apple rejected apps with limited functionality or that doesn't use the iOS platform effectively  but have seen loads of catalogue apps that are exactly that, in particular  one that is just pictures of cars?

Whilst no one here can say if it will or wont be rejected, has anyone had any experience with this type of app and the review process? It seems far more relaxed than other categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the guidelines here:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

I think that when they talk about limited functionality they mean specially stupid apps that do nothing. If your app is useful and has a meaning, it won't be rejected because of that.

Anyway, it's always a guess! You have to take a risk always with this people.

Comment: Yeah I have read those guidelines they are very much open to reviews interpretation though,  you know how it is sometimes with these reviews.   I suppose a catalogue on the ipad would be just that, a digital format of a publication. Thanks for your reply